# Executing blocks of code with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like to execute a block of multiple MySQL queries at the same time (in series, not parallel).  I do not need the operation to be atomic.  Here is a toy example:

[image]

I can accomplish this in MySQL Workbench by moving the cursor from one line to the next and hitting Ctrl+Enter.  Even better, I can select the block and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

However, if I want to quickly run through several such blocks, it becomes unwieldly to have to select each block individually.  I would expect to be able to turn this into a procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE do_sum()
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ttt (col INT);
LOAD DATA INFILE "/var/lib/mysql-files/data.csv" INTO TABLE ttt;
SET @my_sum := (SELECT SUM(col) FROM ttt);
DROP TABLE ttt;
SELECT @my_sum; 
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Unfortunately, this fails with `Error Code 1314. LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedures`.  As the documentation explains, only a subset of commands work inside procedures, excluding things like `LOAD DATA`.

I would like to either

- turn the query into a compound query, like how in `bash` one can execute `echo a && echo b`.  (I have tried `BEGIN ... END` but it doesn't seem to work outside of a construct like `CREATE PROCEDURE`.)
- somehow specify to MySQL Workbench that if I hit Ctrl+Enter when the cursor is anywhere inside this block, then the queries should be executed together.  (MySQL Workbench puts a blue circle between each query and the first line number, so I would want to have a single blue circle in the screenshot above.)

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have to do it from Workbench? If you can use the shell, you can put everything into a file and use `mysql dbname < filename`

Comment: Effectively yes.  I'm using Workbench as my IDE, so it defeats the point if I am instead using the shell.

Comment: I don't use Workbench, but have you tried marking the whole thing with the cursor and then using Ctl-Enter?

Comment: Close.  In my question I state that "I can select the block and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter."  This is a good one-off solution to my problem.  However, it's really annoying when I have multiple blocks which I always execute together, and I need to make selections each time.  I'm trying to somehow avoid having to manually select the block each time.

Comment: Type Ctl-A to select everything at once.

Comment: That selects all blocks.  However, I have multiple blocks in a single file, and I may not wish to execute those blocks sequentially.

Comment: So just select the range of blocks that you want to execute. Click on the beginning, shift-click on the end.

Comment: I already stated in my question that I know how to do that.  I'm looking for a more systematic way to group the queries together into a block.

Comment: I don't think there is one. The only grouping mechanism MySQL has is procedures, and that won't work for you. Can you open multiple workbench windows, so each one has the set of blocks you care about?

Comment: That is an idea, but probably even more annoying than selecting the blocks each time.  

Your statement "*The only grouping mechanism MySQL has is procedures, and that won't work for you*" seems to answer my question.